# Pandas groupby monthly + prorate

Tags: pandas

I have a MultiIndex series:

```
date        xcs    subdomain       count
2012-04-05  111-11 zero            10
2012-04-11  222-22 m               25
2012-04-11  111-11 zero            30
```

Basically the first 3 columns form a unique index.  I need to group by year-month+xcs+subdomain, but count needs to be summed-up, divided by the number of items in that group, and multiplied by 30. Thus for [2012-04, 111-11, zero] group from the above example, it would be (10 + 30)/2*30. I am guessing that this is identical to using average() function for each group, but would still need to multiply it by 30.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do it like this:

Setup your dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = """date        xcs    subdomain       count
2012-04-05  111-11 zero            10
2012-04-11  222-22 m               25
2012-04-11  111-11 zero            30"""
df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(data), sep="\s+")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index(['date', 'xcs', 'subdomain'], inplace=True)
```

Groupby and apply `.mean` multiplying by 30:

```
df['value'] = (df.groupby(level=['date', 'xcs', 'subdomain']).mean() * 30).dropna()
df
```

Yielding:

```
                             count  value
date       xcs    subdomain              
2012-04-05 111-11 zero          10    300
2012-04-11 222-22 m             25    750
           111-11 zero          30    900
```

Comment: is there an incomplete code in df['date']=pd.to_datetime...?

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed that. I guess if you would have provided a code to produce sample dataframe to play with this would not have happened :-)